Is there a way in assembly to change an array's variables?
I found some solution but it doesn't work.
I'm not sure if what I found is really possible.
In that part of the code I tried to do the change:
mov al, [bx+si]
inc ax
mov [bx+si], al

but when I looked at it in the debugger it hadn't changed the values.
Here is the full code:
proc printAllEnemies

mov cx, 4
mov si, 0

pritingLoop:

    mov bx, offset enemiesXYCondition
    push cx
    inc si
    mov al, [bx+si]
    push ax
    inc si
    mov al, [bx+si]
    push ax
    mov [enemyColor], 0
    call print_enemy
    sub si, 2
    mov al, [bx+si]
    cmp ax,0
    je endPritingLoop
    inc si
    mov al, [bx+si]
    inc ax
    mov [bx+si], al
    push ax
    inc si
    mov al, [bx+si]
    push ax
    mov [enemyColor], 11
    call print_enemy 

    endPritingLoop:
    
    pop cx
    add si, 2
    loop pritingLoop
ret
endp printAllEnemies


A lot of push instructions. Where do You use pop?

i use pop in enemyPrint

It's unclear what you want but that piece of code should increment the array value by 1. Also it can be done simply as inc byte ptr [bx+si]

It doesn't make sense to push in the caller and pop in the called function, because the return address is also on the stack. We need to see a [mcve] here. I don't think the three lines you pointed out are the cause of your bug.

There's nothing wrong with having these many pushes for arguments and having them popped in the print_enemy proc as long as you do it via ret 4.
But there is something that doesn't compute in this code! From the way that you're using the array's bytes, it would seem that every record comprises 3 bytes: some kind of status, an X, and a Y. From that I would say that you would need to replace add si,2 by add si,3 near the bottom of the loop.
Currently, if the code that increments the array byte gets skipped, then you will be walking through the array in steps of 2, but if that particular code does get executed, you walk through the array in steps of 4. And neither of these steps is suitable for a record size of 3.
Additionally, cmp ax,0 deals with the 16-bit accumulator where your code only loaded the lowest 8 bits of the accumulator. Are you sure that AH is zero? Better use cmp al,0.
proc printAllEnemies
  mov  cx, 4
  mov  si, 0
pritingLoop:
  mov  bx, offset enemiesXYCondition
  push cx
  mov  al, [bx+si+1]
  push ax
  mov  al, [bx+si+2]
  push ax
  mov  [enemyColor], 0
  call print_enemy
  cmp  byte ptr [bx+si], 0
  je   endPritingLoop
  inc  byte ptr [bx+si+1]
  mov  al, [bx+si+1]
  push ax
  mov  al, [bx+si+2]
  push ax
  mov  [enemyColor], 11
  call print_enemy
endPritingLoop:
  pop  cx
  add  si, 3
  loop pritingLoop
  ret
endp printAllEnemies

